# Reading email from AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, traversal

I'm  trying to get email adress from AD. I Use below code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.SamAccountName = "XXX";
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
var found = srch.FindOne();
```

and this code returns this:
[image]

As You can see using `Local` window I access and read email but I need to do it for ~50 accounts. 
But I can not how to access that place by code.
What should I Write after found

```
found.{something here}.EmailAdress
```

To get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get there I needed to convert `found` into `DirectoryEntry` using this code:

```
var a = found.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
```

And after that I was able to access mail from list of 71 parametres:

```
a.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference here.  You could have just used found.EmailAddress without having to make the extra call for the DirectoryEntry

Comment: If you try to access directly like you want you get: `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal' does not contain a definition for 'EmailAdress' and no extension method 'EmailAdress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` So first I needed to convert it to access. This answer was found be my on the stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah right, didn't pay complete attention.  PrincipalSearcher.FindOne returns a Principal object.  If you cast it as a UserPrincipal you should be able to access the EmailAddress property and thus would not need to get the DirectoryEntry.  Conversely, you could just do a FindByIdentity since you have the sAMAccountName and wrap it up nice and easy.

    `var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var samAccountName = "XXX";
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, samAccountName);
    var email = user.EmailAddress (if user != null that is)`

Comment: Since I can't seem to format the comments correctly here's another note.  Be sure to wrap your PrincipalContext in a using so that get disposed of properly.